# How can I pass a variable for formatResult and formatSelection (select2)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

For example, I have a class:

*classA.js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  select2_scroll('element_name_id')
});
```

calling a function from

*classB.js*

```
function select2_scroll(elementId, queryString) {
resource_url: 'something/';
  $('#' + elementId).select2({
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
      url: resource_url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      quietMillis: 100,
      data: function (term, page) { 
        return {
          search_term: term,
          page: page
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        var more = (page * PAGE_LIMIT) < data.total_results;
        return { results: data.resource, more: more };
      }
    },
    formatResult: resourceName,
    formatSelection: resourceName,
  });
}

function resourceName(resource) {
  var format = '<div>' + resource.name + '</div>' +
           '<input type="hidden" name="' + elementId + '_id" value="' + resource.id + '"/>';

  return format;
}
```

How do I avoid using a global variable to pass the elementId variable? I can't call resourceName directly and pass the elementId in by calling resourceName(resource, elementId).

Am I missing something from the Select2 component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.  I can just do

```
...
formatResult: function(resource) {
      return resourceName(resource, elementId)
    },
formatSelection: function(resource) {
      return resourceName(resource, elementId)
    },
....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
 formatResult: ()=>{
                    resourceName(resource, elementId);
                 },
 formatSelection: ()=>{
                    resourceName(resource, elementId);
                 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your element Id in your "results" return

```
results: function (data, page) {
    var more = (page * PAGE_LIMIT) < data.total_results;
    return { results: data.resource, more: more, elementId: elementId };
  }
```

And use it in your function:

```
var format = '<div>' + resource.name + '</div>' +
       '<input type="hidden" name="' + resource.elementId + '_id" value="' + resource.id + '"/>';
```

Let me know, if this works for you. I didn't have tested it with your example